# Not able to retrieve the HREF from the tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello I am trying to retrieve the 3rd HREF tag from an HTML page. However the following code does not return any result. Any hints/answers would be really useful.The URL that i am trying to parse is as below:

http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html

Code goes like this:

```
 # This python code will parse an html and 
   # find href content from a particular position

   import urllib
   from BeautifulSoup import *

   url = raw_input('Enter - ')
   html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

   # Retrieve all of the anchor tags
   tags = soup('a',limit=3)[2]
   for tag in tags:
      print tag.get('href', None)
```

Comment: I am a beginner and learning Python through Coursera. This is an assignment, so I would prefer hints or any clues to where I am going wrong instead of direct answers :) Thank you!

Comment: post the output of `tags` variable..

Comment: It is better to ask in Coursera forum to help you.

Comment: Yes did that, it returns the desired result i.e. the url from position 3. <a href="http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Montgomery.html">Montgomery</a>

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes tried findAll earlier as well, that is not working.  The error that I get:   raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: replace the last print stmt with `print tag['href']`

Comment: Use newer version - bs4 - `from bs4 import *`

Comment: remove `[2]` if you want to use `for`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Doesnt work.     print tag['href']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
tags = soup('a', limit=3)[2]

print tags.get('href', None)
```

or remove `[2]`

```
tags = soup('a', limit=3)

for tag in tags:
    print tag.get('href', None)
```

Comment: thank you @furas , that was easy to understand and also solved my problem finally! thanks a ton!

Comment: @SIslam Just did! thanks for telling me. I am new to stackoverflow!